# Off-flavors from bottle conditioning, but not kegging

Tags: bottling, kegging, off-flavor

I have brewed some 20l batches where I have kegged half in a 9l corny keg, and bottled the rest with sugar for priming (plain white sucrose). In a couple of these batches the kegged beer has been fantastic, but the bottles have a chemical/fusel-like flavor, and in one batch quinine-like bitterness. None of these flavors were apparent in the kegs, even after several weeks.

The bottles have generally been stored in room temperature (20-21°C) for about two weeks after priming, and then stored cold (3-6°C).

What could be the cause of these off-flavors?

Edit: Thanks for the answers. I was pretty sure that the beer wasn't infected, but I guess I have to accept that I probably was a bit sloppy at some point :-)

Comment: I've given up bottling for this very reason :).  Plus it's a messy pain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like poor sanitation to me.  Be sure you sanitized the bottles well, and that you boiled the sugar in some water first.  Or a contamination could have been picked up during racking with that equipment or the bottling equipment.

Comment: Gotta go with brewchez's answer on this one. Sounds like an infection.

Comment: Same here, have had the same problem and it was cause of infection.

Comment: Also, a smaller concern than sterilizing your sugar by boiling, but consider sanitizing your bottle caps if you currently aren't--especially if you're buying them from a bulk-bin where who-knows-what can get onto them

Answer (score 0):

Using Sucrose (table sugar) to carb could be adding a wineish flavor, I'd recommend switching to corn sugar.

Also, what Brewchez said.

Comment: corn sugar is also known as dextrose or glucose.

Comment: Down voted because when it comes to the amount used for priming, sucrose won't taste winey.  Furthermore, I have used it many times for bottling and its a fine sugar.  Also, I have never experienced cider like qualities when added to a recipe.  Good yeast doesn't create off flavors because of the presence of a super clean sugar.  Whether dextrose, sucrose, glucose or fructose.  Brewing mythology, IMO and experience.